# Python. How to find all occurrences of matched substring?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, html-parsing

I have a big string - html page. I need to find all names of flash drives,
i.e. I need to get content between double quotes: `data-name="USB Flash-drive Leef Fuse 32Gb">`. So I need a string between `data-name="` and `">`. Please, don't mention BeautifulSoup, I need to do it without BeautifulSoup and better without regular expressions, but regular expression are also accepted.

I tried to use this:

```
p = re.compile('(?<=")[^,]+(?=")')
result = p.match(html_str)
print(result)
```

but result is None.
But on regex101.com it worked:
[image]

Comment: What is wrong with using a DOM parser on HTML to extract the value of an attribute?

Comment: @Vasili Syrakis I have certain task - do it using python.

Comment: fyi bs4 = python ; see the first paragraph of this link: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @dot.Py I know that bs4 is python, but I need to do it without help of bs4, only pythons builtin functions or at least regex.

Comment: Python standard library has htmparser (html.parser in py3) which can be used here.

Comment: @dot.Py look again please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

py2: https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

py3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

---

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        # tag = 'sometag'
        for attr in attrs:
            # attr = ('data-name', 'USB Flash-drive Leef Fuse 32Gb')
            if attr[0] == 'data-name':
                print(attr[1])

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<sometag data-name="USB Flash-drive Leef Fuse 32Gb">hello  world</sometag>')
```

Output:

```
USB Flash-drive Leef Fuse 32Gb
```

I've added some comments to the code to show you what kind of data structure is returned by the parser.

It should be very easy to build from here.

Just feed in HTML, and it will parse it fine. Refer to the docs, and keep trying.

Comment: Thanks a lot, God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with basic python string parsing here is a way

```
s="html string"
start = s.find('data-name="')
end = s.find('">')
output = s[start:end]
```

This is what happens in my python shell

```
>>> s='junk...data-name="USB Flash-drive Leef Fuse 32Gb">...junk'
>>> start = s.find('data-name="')
>>> end = s.find('">')
>>> output = s[start:end]
>>> output
'data-name="USB Flash-drive Leef Fuse 32Gb'
```

let me know if this part of script works separately

Comment: iif you are still after a alternate solution could you paste your long html string for me to test

Comment: here is py file that gets flash drives from site and puts them intro 'html_str' string: http://dropmefiles.com/wBvb1